# Bibliography strangeness with pdflatex, bibtex, tufte-handout class

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies, tufte

I'm using TeXLive 2017 and the tufte-handout package. Without the nobib option I get (as usual) a citation in the margin and, strangely, in a References section at the FRONT of the document.

Following suggestions here, if I add the nobib option I get a FIRST page which has a properly formatted References section but the document contents start on page 2 (and no bibliography entries in the margin).  How can I make sure that the References section occurs at the END of the document?  What am I doing wrong?

Here's a minimal example:

```
\documentclass[nols,nobib,letterpaper]{tufte-handout}
\title{Radiation and risk}
\author{D. M. Wood}
\date{}
\begin{document}
\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
\bibliography{samp}
\maketitle% this prints the handout title, author, and date
Blah blah.
See \cite{Charles2007} for more details.
\end{document}
```

with samp.bib containing

```
@article{Charles2007,
author = {Charles, M W and Harrison, J D},
doi = {10.1088/0952-4746/27/3A/S11},
journal = {Journal of radiological protection : official journal of the Society for Radiological Protection},
number = {3A},
pages = {A97--109},
pmid = {17768323},
title = {{Hot particle dosimetry and radiobiology--past and present.}},
volume = {27},
year = {2007}
}
```

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You issued the `\bibliography` command at the start of the document, it's going where you told it to. You could try:

```
\documentclass[nols,nobib,letterpaper]{tufte-handout}
\title{Radiation and risk}
\author{D. M. Wood}
\date{}
\begin{document}
\maketitle% this prints the handout title, author, and date
Blah blah.
See \cite{Charles2007} for more details.
\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
\bibliography{samp}
\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]